# How to get a slice as an array in Rust?

Tags: arrays, rust

I have an array of an unknown size, and I would like to get a slice of that array and convert it to a statically sized array:

```
fn pop(barry: &[u8]) -> [u8; 3] {
    barry[0..3] // expected array `[u8; 3]`, found slice `[u8]`
}
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 186, accepted):

You can easily do this with the [`TryInto`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryInto.html) trait (which was stabilized in Rust 1.34):

```rust
// Before Rust 2021, you need to import the trait:
// use std::convert::TryInto;

fn pop(barry: &[u8]) -> [u8; 3] {
    barry.try_into().expect("slice with incorrect length")
}
```

But even better: there is no need to clone/copy your elements! It is actually possible to get a `&[u8; 3]` from a `&[u8]`:

```rust
fn pop(barry: &[u8]) -> &[u8; 3] {
    barry.try_into().expect("slice with incorrect length")
}
```

As mentioned in the other answers, you probably don't want to panic if the length of `barry` is not 3, but instead handle this error gracefully.

This works thanks to these impls of the related trait [`TryFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html) (before Rust 1.47, these only existed for arrays up to length 32):

```rust
impl<'_, T, const N: usize> TryFrom<&'_ [T]> for [T; N]
where
    T: Copy, 

impl<'a, T, const N: usize> TryFrom<&'a [T]> for &'a [T; N]

impl<'a, T, const N: usize> TryFrom<&'a mut [T]> for &'a mut [T; N]
```

Comment: Now `impl<'a, T> TryFrom<&'a [T]> for [T; $N] where T: Copy` has been provided as well (`[T; $N]` vs `&'a [T; $N]`).

Comment: How can this be done if your array is bigger than 32 bytes?

Comment: @Alvaro Check the other answers for this. Until const generics are stable, my answer only works up to the size of 32.

Comment: I ended up copying this from the standard lib for the size I required (luckily it's for a very specific size)

Comment: Another syntax, from a `Vec`: `<[i32; 2]>::try_from(&vec[..])`

Comment: Are you aware of an unsafe counter-part? E.g. when using `chunks_exact` there is a guarantee.

Comment: @JorgeLeitao You can probably just use `TryFrom` and put an `unreachable_unchecked` on the error branch. Or use pointer casts on `[T]::as_ptr`. And even though it's still unstable right now, you might be interested in `[T]::array_chunks` which solves this problem much nicer!

Answer (score 22):

Thanks to [@malbarbo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37679019/147192) we can use this helper function:

```
use std::convert::AsMut;

fn clone_into_array<A, T>(slice: &[T]) -> A
where
    A: Default + AsMut<[T]>,
    T: Clone,
{
    let mut a = A::default();
    <A as AsMut<[T]>>::as_mut(&mut a).clone_from_slice(slice);
    a
}
```

to get a much neater syntax:

```
fn main() {
    let original = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

    let e = Example {
        a: clone_into_array(&original[0..4]),
        b: clone_into_array(&original[4..10]),
    };

    println!("{:?}", e);
}
```

as long as `T: Default + Clone`.

If you know your type implements `Copy`, you can use this form:

```
use std::convert::AsMut;

fn copy_into_array<A, T>(slice: &[T]) -> A
where
    A: Default + AsMut<[T]>,
    T: Copy,
{
    let mut a = A::default();
    <A as AsMut<[T]>>::as_mut(&mut a).copy_from_slice(slice);
    a
}
```

Both variants will `panic!` if the target array and the passed-in slice do not have the same length.

Comment: in line `let mut a = Default::default();` probably should be `let mut a = A::default();` or not?

Comment: @KostyaKrivomaz: Either works. `<A as Default>::default()` is yet another variation.

Comment: Clippy would prefer `A::default()` because it's more explicit.

Comment: @Jocelyn: Better toe the line then!

Answer (score 19):

I recommend using the crate [arrayref](https://crates.io/crates/arrayref), which has a handy macro for doing just this.

Note that, using this crate, you create a reference to an array, `&[u8; 3]`, because it doesn't clone any data!

If you *do* want to clone the data, then you can still use the macro, but call clone at the end:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate arrayref;

fn pop(barry: &[u8]) -> &[u8; 3] {
    array_ref!(barry, 0, 3)
}
```

or

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate arrayref;

fn pop(barry: &[u8]) -> [u8; 3] {
    array_ref!(barry, 0, 3).clone()
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Here's a function that matches the type signature you asked for.

```
fn pop(barry: &[u8]) -> [u8; 3] {
    [barry[0], barry[1], barry[2]]
}
```

But since `barry` could have fewer than three elements, you may want to return an `Option<[u8; 3]>` rather than a `[u8; 3]`.

```
fn pop(barry: &[u8]) -> Option<[u8; 3]> {
    if barry.len() < 3 {
        None
    } else {
        Some([barry[0], barry[1], barry[2]])
    }
}
```

Comment: ‒​​​​​​​​​1​​​ because the generic case isn't answered (e.g. `[u8; 32]`; nobody will repeat acesss by index 32 times)

Comment: @diralik And yet there's people who do... Until const generics are stabilized, this is still the best way. Current rust std quite literally has an unstable trait that ensures array length up to 32 and then implements most traits that make sense to be implemented for every single array type up to 32 times...

That's just how reality is right now. You can write code generator that outputs 0 to N array code code at will to make it somewhat better, this answer is good and shows how std does it. Or are you just going to say "tough luck, see you in 5 years" for array of size 33?

Comment: Update: const generics are stabilized ;)

Answer (score 15):

You can manually create the array and return it.

Here is a function that can easily scale if you want to get more (or less) than 3 elements.

Note that if the slice is too small, the end terms of the array will be 0's.

```
fn pop(barry: &[u8]) -> [u8; 3] {
    let mut array = [0u8; 3];
    for (&x, p) in barry.iter().zip(array.iter_mut()) {
        *p = x;
    }
    array
}
```

Comment: Would prefer a generic function - needing to define functions for each type would get annoying if you ever need to use this for a non `u8`.

Answer (score 3):

I was unhappy with other answers because I needed several functions that return varying length fixed u8 arrays. I wrote a macro that produces functions specific for the task. Hope it helps someone.

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! vec_arr_func {
    ($name:ident, $type:ty, $size:expr) => {
        pub fn $name(data: std::vec::Vec<$type>) -> [$type; $size] {
            let mut arr = [0; $size];
            arr.copy_from_slice(&data[0..$size]);
            arr
        }
    };
}

//usage - pass in a name for the fn, type of array, length
vec_arr_func!(v32, u8, 32);
v32(data); //where data is std::vec::Vec<u8>
```

Comment: What's *wrong* with the other answers to make you unhappy? What's *better* about this?

Comment: What do you mean by "function printing macro"?

Comment: By the way, its not idiomatic to use `return` at the end of the function.

Comment: It's needless to accept a `Vec` here: [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423)

Comment: This is effectively the same code as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37682288/155423), except it uses a macro.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I'm new to Rust. What was not clear with the other answers is if we could vary the length of the fixed array being returned. I couldn't figure out how to do this with a function so resorted to a macro. You're right the return is a habit 

Answer (score 2):

The nice common thing between `Vec`, 'Slice' and `Array` is `Iter`, so you can `zip` and `map` both together, as simple as:

```rust
let x = vec![1, 2, 3];
let mut y: [u8; 3] = [Default::default(); 3];
println!("y at startup: {:?}", y);    
x.iter().zip(y.iter_mut()).map(|(&x, y)| *y = x).count();
println!("y copied from vec: {:?}", y);
```

[image]

This is as the array is 1 dimensional array.

To test all together, vec, slice and array, [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3f474f87924b8f552b68cc6e80bbe000) you go:

```rust
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let slice = &a[1..4];
let mut x: Vec<u8> = vec![Default::default(); 3];
println!("X at startup: {:?}", x);    
slice.iter().zip(x.iter_mut()).map(|(&s, x)| *x = s).count();
println!("X copied from vec: {:?}", x);
```

[image]

Another option which should be faster than byte-by-byte copy is:

```rust
y[..x.len()].copy_from_slice(&x);
```

Which is applicable for all, below is example:

```rust
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let mut b: Vec<u8> = vec![Default::default(); 5];
b[..a.len()].copy_from_slice(&a);
println!("Copy array a into vector b: {:?}", b);

let x: Vec<u8> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let mut y: [u8; 5] = [Default::default(); 5];
y[..x.len()].copy_from_slice(&x);
println!("Copy vector x into array y: {:?}", y);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting that if your array is a string, e.g. if you want to convert `&'static str -> [u32; N]`, then you can sometimes just initialize your original string as `b"my string"` instead. The `b""` syntax in Rust creates statically-known-size arrays of bytes (e.g. `&[u8, 32]`).

Answer (score 0):

[Const generics](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2000-const-generics.html) were stabilized in Rust version 1.51.0, released in 2021. You can utilize const generics to implement a function that converts a slice into an array of any fixed size:

```rust
fn array<T: Copy, const N: usize>(slice: &[T]) -> [T; N] {
    slice.try_into().expect("Slice has the wrong length")
}
```

Example:

```rust
let slice: &[u8] = &[10, 20, 30];
let array: [u8; 3] = array(slice);
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this. This only saves you an `expect()`, and that hides the possibility of failure.

Comment: I favor the cleaner syntax of `Ipv4Addr::from(array(payload))` compared to `Ipv4Addr::from(<[u8; 4]>::try_from(payload).expect(SLICE_ERROR_MSG))`.

Comment: Sure, but at least add a big `# Panics` headline in the docs.