# Differences in syntax for invoking trait method on generic type

Tags: rust

I'm trying to understand the need for the `Trait::` and `<T as Trait>::` method invocation syntax. In particular, I'm looking at the following function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38169182/394331):

```
fn clone_into_array<A, T>(slice: &[T]) -> A
where
    A: Default + AsMut<[T]>,
    T: Clone,
{
    assert_eq!(
        slice.len(),
        std::mem::size_of::<A>() / std::mem::size_of::<T>()
    );

    let mut a = Default::default();
    <A as AsMut<[T]>>::as_mut(&mut a).clone_from_slice(slice);
    a
}
```

It seems that the middle two method invocation lines can be rewritten as:

```
let mut a = A::default();
a.as_mut().clone_from_slice(slice);
```

I believe this is more readable, as we already know that `A` implements `Default` and `AsMut<[T]>` and we can invoke `as_mut` directly as a method instead of having to pass `a` to it explicitly.

However, am I missing a good reason for the linked answer to have written it more verbosely? Is it considered good style? Are the two semantically different under certain conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your rewrites — they are more clear and are what I would recommend for that function.

> am I missing a good reason for the linked answer to have written it more verbosely?

My guess is that the author simply was tired of writing that function and stopped. If they took a look at it again, they might refine it to be shorter.

> Is it considered good style?

I don't think there's a general community stylistic preference around this yet, other than the general "shorter is better until it isn't".

> Are the two semantically different under certain conditions?

They shouldn't be.

---

There are times where the `<>::` syntax *is* needed because otherwise it would be ambiguous. One example [from a recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48129778/155423):

```
let array = <&mut [u8; 3]>::try_from(slice);
```

Another time is when you don't have a nicely-named intermediate type or the intermediate type is ambiguous across multiple traits. One [gross example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47880065/155423) is from a `where` clause but shows the same issue as an expression would:

```
<<Tbl as OrderDsl<Desc<Expr>>>::Output as LimitDsl>::Output: QueryId,
```

See also:

- [How to call a method when a trait and struct use the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44445730/155423)