# How can I check, at compile-time, that a slice is a specific size?

Tags: rust

I'd like to check, at compile-time, that a slice used in a `From` implementation is a specific size.

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=67e22b36df79557f472457ec6a5464b4))

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Pixel {
    r: u8,
    g: u8,
    b: u8,
}

impl From<&[u8]> for Pixel {
    fn from(arr: &[u8]) -> Pixel {
        Pixel {
            r: arr[0],
            g: arr[1],
            b: arr[2],
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    let arr: [u8; 9] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    let pixels: Vec<Pixel> = arr.chunks_exact(3).map(Pixel::from).collect();
    println!("{:.?}", pixels);
}
```

This is not as specific as I'd like. I'd like to check the `arr` passed to `Pixel::from<&[u8]>()` is 3 elements as clearly as possible (at compile time).

Thought of `assert!(arr.len()==3)`, but this checks at runtime.

So I thought maybe I could do the conversion by ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fadf9c53b2db738f2b929d4fbf8c514b)):

```rust
impl From<[u8; 3]> for Pixel {
    fn from(arr: [u8; 3]) -> Pixel {
        Pixel {
            r: arr[0],
            g: arr[1],
            b: arr[2],
        }
    }
}
```

but this leads to:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Pixel: From<&[u8]>` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:22:30
    |
22  |       let pixels: Vec<Pixel> = arr.chunks_exact(3).map(Pixel::from).collect();
    |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<&[u8]>` is not implemented for `Pixel`
    |
    = help: the following implementations were found:
              <Pixel as From<[u8; 3]>>

error[E0277]: the trait bound `Pixel: From<&[u8]>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:22:54
   |
22 |     let pixels: Vec<Pixel> = arr.chunks_exact(3).map(Pixel::from).collect();
   |                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<&[u8]>` is not implemented for `Pixel`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <Pixel as From<[u8; 3]>>
   = note: required by `from`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `Pixel: From<&[u8]>` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:22:30
    |
22  |       let pixels: Vec<Pixel> = arr.chunks_exact(3).map(Pixel::from).collect();
    |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<&[u8]>` is not implemented for `Pixel`
    |
    = help: the following implementations were found:
              <Pixel as From<[u8; 3]>>
```

Similarly I tried `From<&[u8; 3]>` but same result.

Is there a way to implement from for a specific sized slice?

This is a not a duplicate of [How to convert a slice into an array reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48129565/155423) as this question specifically relates to checking at compile-time without runtime performance effects, it is not casting `&[u8]` to `&[u8; 3]` rather simply checking at compile time `&[u8]` has 3 elements (which may be done via using `&[u8; 3]`). All answers to the aforementioned question incur runtime affects, except I believe this approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48129731/4301453) (applied like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4adee0ce74a12e676893d682b23b87f7)) but this does not check at all that the slice is the appropriate length. This question is not specifically about being able to use `Pixel::from<[u8;3]>` but rather about generally checking the length at compile time, which none of these answers offer or relate to.

Comment: https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuple_windows could be use but this will anyway do runtime check and could hide error

Comment: @Shepmaster Added explanation of why this is not a duplicate. So if I'm understanding this, it cannot be done in stable because it requires const generic and would be done with `slice::array_chunks`? If that's right that seems a reasonable if somewhat unsatisfying answer (having to simply wait till const generics become stable that is).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do this at compile time because *slice lengths are not known at compile time*. That's a big reason that slices exist in the first place. When the length is known at compile time, that's an array.

See also:

- [What is the difference between a slice and an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30794235/155423)
- [How to set a Rust array length dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34684261/155423)
- [Take slice of certain length known at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38168956/155423)

---

I'd instead write both fallible and infallible conversions:

```rust
use std::array::TryFromSliceError;
use std::convert::TryFrom;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Pixel {
    r: u8,
    g: u8,
    b: u8,
}

impl TryFrom<&[u8]> for Pixel {
    type Error = TryFromSliceError;

    fn try_from(arr: &[u8]) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        <&[u8; 3]>::try_from(arr).map(Self::from)
    }
}

impl From<&[u8; 3]> for Pixel {
    fn from(arr: &[u8; 3]) -> Self {
        Self::from(*arr)
    }
}

impl From<[u8; 3]> for Pixel {
    fn from(arr: [u8; 3]) -> Self {
        Pixel {
            r: arr[0],
            g: arr[1],
            b: arr[2],
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can convert from an array, allowing for a compile time error, or when you have a slice and don't know the length at compile time, you can attempt to convert and have a run-time error.

In the future, you can use methods like [`slice::array_chunks`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.array_chunks) to convert a slice into an iterator of arrays. However, there's *still* the case that the slice wasn't the right length (too long or short) that you have to handle somehow.

Comment: I would add, that this can be accomplished in nightly using [`slice::array_chunks`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.array_chunks) like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d6b253da179b3b8303f925720cac332c).

Comment: @JonathanWoollett-light but that _doesn't solve your problem_. You won't get a compiler error [when the slice isn't evenly divisible](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eb79428f078e91a2ac8bbdcb79e1d825), which is what you've asked.

Comment: It doesn't check `arr` is the appropriate size, but it does check the chunks are the appropriate length (`array_chunks::<4>()` will raise a compile time error while `chunks(4)` will not) a step in the direction of clarity I think at least. Originally this was what my focus was on (I messed up not presenting `arr` as a `Vec` I now realise, it was misleading I see).