# Dereference FFI pointer in Python to get underlying array

Tags: python, rust, cffi

I have a C FFI written in Rust, called `src/lib.rs` that looks like the following:

```rust
// compile with $ cargo build

extern crate libc;
use self::libc::{size_t, int32_t};

use std::cmp::min;
use std::slice;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn rle_new(values_data: *const int32_t, values_length: size_t) -> *mut Rle {
    let values = unsafe { slice::from_raw_parts(values_data, values_length as usize).to_vec() };

    return Box::into_raw(Box::new(Rle::new(values)));

}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn rle_free(ptr: *mut Rle) {
    if ptr.is_null() {
        return;
    }
    unsafe {
        Box::from_raw(ptr);
    }
}  

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn rle_values_size(rle: *mut Rle) -> int32_t {
    unsafe { (*rle).values.len() as i32 }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn rle_values(rle: *mut Rle) -> *mut int32_t {
    unsafe { &mut (*rle).values[0] }
}


#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct Rle {
    pub values: Vec<i32>,
}


impl Rle {
    pub fn new(values: Vec<i32>) -> Self {
        return Rle { values: values };
    }
}
```

This is my Cargo.toml in the project base folder:

```
[package]
name = "minimal_example"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Dumbass"]

[dependencies]
libc = "0.2.16"

[lib]
crate-type = ["dylib"] # you might need a different type on linux/windows ?
```

This is the Python code calling Rust, also put in the base folder:

```py
import os
import sys, ctypes
from ctypes import c_char_p, c_uint32, Structure, POINTER, c_int32, c_size_t, pointer

class RleS(Structure):
    pass

prefix = {'win32': ''}.get(sys.platform, 'lib')
extension = {'darwin': '.dylib', 'win32': '.dll'}.get(sys.platform, '.so')
libpath = os.environ.get("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", "target/debug") + "/"
libpath = libpath + prefix + "minimal_example" + extension

try:
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libpath)
except OSError:
    print("Library not found at " + libpath)
    sys.exit()

lib.rle_new.restype = POINTER(RleS)

lib.rle_free.argtypes = (POINTER(RleS), )

lib.rle_values.argtypes = (POINTER(RleS), )
lib.rle_values.restypes = POINTER(c_int32)

lib.rle_values_size.argtypes = (POINTER(RleS), )
lib.rle_values_size.restypes = c_int32


class Rle:
    def __init__(self, values):

        values_length =  len(values)

        values_array = (c_int32 * len(values))(*values)

        self.obj = lib.rle_new(values_array, c_size_t(values_length))

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        lib.rle_free(self.obj)

    def __str__(self):
        values_size = lib.rle_values_size(self.obj)
        print(values_size, "values_size") # prints correct value

        values_pointer = lib.rle_values(self.obj)
        print("values_pointer:", values_pointer)
        ar = ctypes.cast(values_pointer, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int32)).contents
        print(ar) # segfaults!

rle = Rle([1, 1, 2] * 10)
print(rle)
```

I have good reason to believe that the C code is correct, since the `rle_values_size` and `rle_values` refer to the same object, namely a Rust vector within a struct, and the `rle_values_size` function works.

However, when I try to dereference the pointer given by `rle_values` and read it as an array I get segfaults.

I have tried every single permutation of code snippets I have found on Stack Overflow, but it segfaults.

Why is this crashing? What am I doing wrong?

I added the Rust tag since I might be getting the address of the vector in the wrong way.

Ps. If somebody also knows how to read this directly into a numpy array I would upvote that too.

Background info: [How do I return an array in a pub extern "C" fn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40156545/how-do-i-return-an-array-in-a-pub-extern-c-fn/40170400?noredirect=1#comment67624063_40170400)

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks for pushing me to make the example completely reproducible. That was my main problem with other very similar questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cast` should be the first warning sign. Why do you have to cast from the type to what should be the same type? This is because there are simple typos:

```py
lib.rle_values.restype = POINTER(c_int32)    
lib.rle_values_size.restype = c_int32
```

Note that it's supposed to be `restype`, not `restypes`.

```py
def __str__(self):
    values_size = lib.rle_values_size(self.obj)
    print(values_size, "values_size")

    values_pointer = lib.rle_values(self.obj)
    print("values_pointer:", values_pointer)

    thing = values_pointer[:values_size]
    return str(thing)
```

It's also better to use `as_mut_ptr`:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn rle_values(rle: *mut Rle) -> *mut int32_t {
    let mut rle = unsafe { &mut *rle };
    rle.values.as_mut_ptr()
}
```

Running the program appears to work:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD/target/debug/ python3 main.py
new
30 values_size
values_pointer: <__main__.LP_c_int object at 0x10f124048>
[1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2]
```

---

I'd also recommend:

- the default ctypes return value is a `cint`. Not specifying a return type for `free` is probably not a good idea, as it should be `void`.
- return an unsigned number for the length of the data; what would -53 items mean?
- reduce the scope of the `unsafe` blocks to just the part that is unsafe and the code that ensures it is actually safe.
- speaking of which, you could check for `NULL` pointers in each function.

  ```
  #[no_mangle]
  pub extern "C" fn rle_values_size(rle: *mut Rle) -> int32_t {
      match unsafe { rle.as_ref() } {
          Some(rle) => rle.values.len() as i32,
          None => 0,
      }
  }

  #[no_mangle]
  pub extern "C" fn rle_values(rle: *mut Rle) -> *mut int32_t {
      match unsafe { rle.as_mut() } {
          Some(mut rle) => rle.values.as_mut_ptr(),
          None => ptr::null_mut(),
      }
  }
  ```