# How do I explicitly tell the Rust compiler the length of an array slice?

Tags: types, rust

Let's assume I have the following slice (code does not compile):

```
struct Data {
  data: Vec<u8>
}

impl Data {

  pub fn parse_ipv4(&self) -> Ipv4Addr {
    let octets: [u8; 4] = self.data[2..6]; // this does not compile
    Some(Ipv4Addr::from(octets));
  }
}
```

The problem is that the compiler cannot infer the `usize` of the slice of `data`, so how do I explicitly tell it the length of the new array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a slice as an array in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428920/how-to-get-a-slice-as-an-array-in-rust)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is `TryInto`. It looks like you meant to return `Option<Ipv4Addr>` so I added that in.

```
use std::net::Ipv4Addr;
use std::convert::TryInto;

struct Data {
    data: Vec<u8>
}

impl Data {
    pub fn parse_ipv4(&self) -> Option<Ipv4Addr> {
        let octets: Result<[u8; 4], _> = self.data[2..6].try_into();
        octets.map(Ipv4Addr::from).ok()
    }
}
```