# How to copy or reference a slice of bytes?

Tags: arrays, rust, slice

How can I copy, or reference a slice of bytes from a larger array?

I only need to read them, but I want the size to be specified to catch errors at compile-time.

```
let foo = rand::thread_rng().gen::<[u8; 32]>();
let bar: [u8; 16] = foo[0..16];
let baz: &[u8; 16] = &foo[16..32];
```

The errors are:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:64:22
   |
64 |     let bar: [u8; 16] = foo[0..16];
   |              --------   ^^^^^^^^^^ expected array `[u8; 16]`, found slice `[u8]`
   |              |
   |              expected due to this
    
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:65:23
   |
65 |     let baz: &[u8; 16] = &foo[16..32];
   |              ---------   ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected array `[u8; 16]`, found slice `[u8]`
   |              |
   |              expected due to this
   |
   = note: expected reference `&[u8; 16]`
              found reference `&[u8]`
```

I can see that `foo[0..16]` is exactly 16 bytes, not a slice of unknown length `[u8]`.  How do I help the compiler see this?

Comment: For this particular case I would just do: `let mut bar = [0; 16]; bar.copy_from_slice(&foo[0..16]);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't that you can't reference a slice of bytes; it's that a slice is not an array.

Probably you want [the arrayref crate](https://github.com/droundy/arrayref) or [the `TryInto` trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428920/how-to-get-a-slice-as-an-array-in-rust). There's also some discussion on doing this automatically [in this Github issue.](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1772)