# Rust: can I have a fixed size slice by borrowing the whole fixed size array in a smaller scope in a simple way

Tags: rust, slice, lifetime, borrow-checker

I saw the workarounds and they where kinda long. Am I missing a feature of Rust or a simple solution (Important: not workaround). I feel like I should be able to do this with maybe a simple macro but arrayref crate implementations aren't what I am looking for. Is this a feature that needs to be added to Rust or creating fixed size slicing from fixed sized array in a **smaller scope** is something bad.
Basically what I want to do is this;

```rust
fn f(arr:[u8;4]){
    arr[0];
}

fn basic(){
    let mut arr:[u8;12] = [0;12];
    // can't I borrow the whole array but but a fixed slice to it?
    f(&mut arr[8..12]); // But this is know on compile time?
    f(&mut arr[8..12] as &[u8;4]); // Why can't I do these things?
}
```

What I want can be achieved by below code(from other so threads)

```rust
use array_ref;

fn foo(){
    let buf:[u8;12] = [0;12];
    let (_, fixed_slice) = mut_array_refs![
        &mut buf,
        8,
        4
    ];
    write_u32_into(fixed_slice,0);
}

fn write_u32_into(fixed_slice:&mut [u8;12],num:u32){
    // won't have to check if fixed_slice.len() == 12 and won't panic
}
```

But I looked into the crate and even though this never panics there are many unsafe blocks and many lines of code. It is a workaround for the Rust itself. In the first place I wanted something like this to get rid of the overhead of checking the size and the possible runtime panic.

Also this is a little overhead it doesn't matter isn't a valid answer because technically I should be able to guarantee this in compile time even if the overhead is small this doesn't mean rust doesn't need to have this type of feature or I should not be looking for an ideal way.
Note: Can this be solved with lifetimes?

Edit: If we where able to have a different syntax for fixed slices such as arr[12;;16] and when I borrowed them this way it would borrow it would borrow the whole arr. I think this way many functions for example ([write_u32](https://docs.rs/byteorder/1.4.2/byteorder/trait.WriteBytesExt.html#method.write_u32)) would be implemented in a more "rusty" way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a slice as an array in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428920/how-to-get-a-slice-as-an-array-in-rust)

Comment: No, this might panic in runtime. I indicated in the question.

Comment: What do you mean 'this is runtime'?

Comment: I mean that it might panic in runtime.

Comment: It can't panic in runtime, it's unreachable code.

Comment: And if you're worried about the performance in a very tight loop, you can use `.try_into().unwrap_or_else(|_| unsafe { std::hint::unreachable_unchecked() })`.

Comment: Ok this looks like a better workaround than array_refs! macro. Is this available in non std? Also shouldn't there be a better way... what I am trying to figure out essentially is this a feature rust should have or is there any way without nasty unsafe blocks. We know that what I want isn't unsafe technically

Comment: Sorry I'm not particularly interested in discussing this further.

Comment: What you want may be possible when const generics is better supported, but I haven't looked at this specific case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use let binding with `slice_patterns` feature. It was stabilized in Rust 1.42.

```rust
let v = [1, 2, 3]; // inferred [i32; 3]
let [_, ref subarray @ ..] = v; // subarray is &[i32; 2]
let a = v[0]; // 1
let b = subarray[1]; // 3
```

[Here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/patterns.html#slice-patterns) is a section from the Rust reference about slice patterns.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I knew there should be a feature for this. I guess I should read the rust reference again. After I test this I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Why it doesn't work

What you want is not available as a feature in rust stable or nightly because multiple things related to const are not stabilized yet, namely const generics and const traits. The reason traits are involved is because the `arr[8..12]` is a call to the `core::ops::Index::<Range<usize>>` trait that returns a reference to a slice, in your case `[u8]`. This type is unsized and not equal to `[u8; 4]` even if the compiler could figure out that it is, rust is inherently safe and can be overprotective sometimes to ensure safety.

## What can you do then?

You have a few routes you can take to solve this issue, I'll stay in a `no_std` environment for all this as that seems to be where you're working and will avoid extra crates.

### Change the function signature

The current function signature you have takes the four `u8`s as an owned value. If you only are asking for 4 values you can instead take those values as parameters to the function. This option breaks down when you need larger arrays but at that point, it would be better to take the array as a reference or using the method below.

The most common way, and the best way in my opinion, is to take the array in as a reference to a slice (`&[u8]` or `&mut [u8]`). This is not the same as taking a pointer to the value in C, slices in rust also carry the length of themselves so you can safely iterate through them without worrying about buffer overruns or if you read all the data. This does require changing the algorithms below to account for variable-sized input but most of the time there is a just as good option to use.

### The safe way

Slice can be converted to arrays using `TryInto`, but this comes at the cost of runtime size checking which you seem to want to avoid. This is an option though and may result in a minimal performance impact.

Example:

```
fn f(arr: [u8;4]){
  arr[0];
}

fn basic(){
  let mut arr:[u8;12] = [0;12];
  f(arr[8..12].try_into().unwrap());
}
```

### The unsafe way

If you're willing to leave the land of safety there are quite a few things you can do to force the compiler to recognize the data as you want it to, but they can be abused. It's usually better to use rust idioms rather than force other methods in but this is a valid option.

```
fn basic(){
  let mut arr:[u8;12] = [0;12];
  f(unsafe {*(arr[8..12].as_ptr() as *const [u8; 4])});
}
```

## TL;DR

I recommend changing your types to utilize slices rather than arrays but if that's not feasible I'd suggest avoiding unsafety, the performance won't be as bad as you think.

Comment: I was going to give up hope and use Vec but @Deadbeef's answer is what I was looking for. I know the overhead is minimal but I was bothered with the idea that rust didn't have this feature.

Comment: I didn't even know that was a thing, it's really helpful!