# How to construct a Type containing a slice in Rust

Tags: arrays, rust, types, initialization

I want to create a type containing an array allocated to the stack.

```rust
struct MyStruct {
    values: [u8; 25],
}
```

I'm not able to implement the `MyStruct::new()` trait to initialize the struct's array.

Here's my unsuccessful atempt:

```rust
impl MyStruct {
    fn new(numbers: &[u8]) -> Self  {
        Self  {
            values: numbers.copy_from_slice(),
        }
    }
}
```

I encountered some solutions on the internet, but they all either initialize the array to 0 or use the heap with `Vec<u8>`.

I can't find anything on the internet other than "use a vector" solutions.
How do I `memcpy` arrays in a safe way in rust?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a slice as an array in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428920/how-to-get-a-slice-as-an-array-in-rust) You'd do `numbers.try_into().unwrap()` with potentially handling the error properly in case the slice has more or fewer elements than the array requires.

Comment: @kmdreko it does. Thanks a lot for your help.